# what i am doing wrong on laravel filter request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

**4 ecommerce site**
i am trying to filter my data but something i am doing wrong
Every filter is working fine like colors brands price but when i filter gender its returning data when i `dd($products)` on after of if gender section
But when i `dd($products)` before return views its returning 0 data means nothing
here is my `form`

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'category/' . $tag . '/filter', 'files'=>false, 'id' => 'color_form'])   !!}

    Price Filter 
    <input name="price" id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="2000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[250,450]" onchange="checkBoxHandler()"/>

    <li class="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" id="men" value="male" onchange="checkBoxHandler()"> Men's
    </li>

    <li class="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" id="woman" value="female" onchange="checkBoxHandler()"> Woman's
    </li>

    @foreach($colors as $color)
        <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" id="color{{ $color->name }}" value="{{ $color->name }}" onchange="checkBoxHandler()">
        <div style="width:25px; height:25px; background:{{ $color->name }}; border:1px solid black; margin:0px 3px 0px 3px;  display:inline-block;"></div> &nbsp {{ $color->name }}
    @endforeach

    @foreach($brands as $brand)
        <input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" id="brand{{ $brand->name }}" value="{{ $brand->name }}" onchange="checkBoxHandler()">
        {{ $brand->name }}<br>
    @endforeach

    @foreach($sizes as $size)
        <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="size{{ $size->name }}" value="{{ $size->name }}" onchange="checkBoxHandler()">
        {{ $size->name }}<br>
    @endforeach

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

here is my `controller`

```
public function newinindex(Request $request){
  if(request()->has('gender')||request()->has('price')||request()->has('color')||request()->has('brand')){
      if (request()->has('gender')) {
         $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->where('gender', request('gender'))->newin()->paginate(20);
      }
      if (request()->has('price')) {
          $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->newin()->whereBetween('price', explode(',', $request->price))->paginate(20);
      }
      if (request()->has('color')) {
             $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->newin()->whereHas('colors', function ($query) {
              $query->where('name', request('color'));
          })->paginate(20);
      }
      if (request()->has('brand')) {
         $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->newin()->whereHas('brands', function ($query) {
              $query->where('name', request('brand'));
          })->paginate(20);
      }
    }
    else  {
       $products = product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->newin()->paginate(20);
    } 
  $sizes = size::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  $colors = color::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
  $brands = brand::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);

  return view('newin.index' ,compact('products', 'brands', 'colors', 'sizes'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The gender field is an array! Please refer to the following link and try using the value in the field name.

[example](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14056)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `gender` checkbox as an array. Modify your `controller` like

```
$products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->whereIn('gender', request('gender'))->newin()->paginate(20);
```

The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.

More about [**Laravel whereIn**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Hope it's helpful.